# How can I format decimal places based on values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I format a number in Excel so that if it's a whole number with a decimal, it goes to the 10th, but if it doesn't have a whole number it goes to 100th?

Example:

```
0.08 -> 0.08
0.02 -> 0.02
1.66 -> 1.6
2.55 -> 2.5
2.89 - > 2.8
3.66 -> 3.6
5 -> 5
8 -> 8
```

Edit:

So far the formula provided by JvdV is working

```
=IF(A1-INT(A1)>0.1,ROUNDDOWN(A1,1),A1)
```

but needs to adjust for the following:

1) I need anything with 0.1 to contain its original value. With the current formula above this changes 0.15 to 0.10.

Example:

```
0.11 -> 0.11
0.15 -> 0.15
0.16 -> 0.16
0.19 -> 0.19
```

2) The formula needs to round up .01 to .09 only when they have a whole number in front of them.

Example:

```
0.01 - > 0.01
0.07 -> 0.07
0.09 -> 0.09
0.99 -> 0.99
1 -> 1
1.01 -> 1.1
1.02 -> 1.1
1.04 -> 1.1
1.05 -> 1.1
1.06 -> 1.1
1.07 -> 1.1
1.08 -> 1.1
1.09 -> 1.1
2.01 -> 2.1
2.04 -> 2.1
3.03 -> 3.1
3.09 -> 3.1
```

This is tricky because 0.01 should be formatted as 0.01. 0.02 should be formatted as 0.02, etc. Currently, the formula does this but does not round up for whole numbers.

Comment: i don't need to round 1.66 up to 1.7, just would like to remove the last decimal place

Comment: What happens with `0.55` and `1.02`?

Comment: I'm lost with where you going, read this line `"The formula needs to round up .01 to .09 only when they have a whole number in front of them."` and pls explain why you then round up to the nearest 10th? What would happen with values like 1.13. Would that become 1.1 like your original question? Or 1.2

Comment: 0.55 -> 0.55, 1.02 -> 1.1, 1.13 -> 1.1 (like my original question), 1.16 -> 1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess something like this could work:

```
=IF(A1-INT(A1)>0.1,ROUNDDOWN(A1,1),A1)
```

---

After your edited question, my edited answer would look like:

```
=IF(A1>1,IF(A1-INT(A1)>0.1,ROUNDDOWN(A1,1),ROUNDUP(A1,1)),A1)
```

Comment: This is working great. One adjustment I'd like to make is to round 3.01 to 3.09 ->  3.1; or 4.01 to 4.09 to 4.1. 5.01 to 5.09 -> 5.1, etc. How can I edit this formula to do this?

Comment: also this is formatting .11 as .10. i need it to remain .11

Comment: Doesn't this do exactly what you stated in your question and comment? When there is no first decimal, it will keep the 100s. When there is a first decimal it removes the 100s. If this is not what you expect than your question might just not be clear enough

Comment: you are right and i will edit my question accordingly. if you have any suggestions on how to edit your formula above to account for my comments it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, edited the answer for now to accomodate your new criteria. Worked on my end @a2b123

Comment: you're a wizard harry! thank you so much for the help, this is working great on my end!!!

Comment: I'm not a wizard!! ( I see where you referring to there haha )

Comment: The second formula will work in a column with no specific format i.e. `General` format. If the column has a predetermined format such as `#,##0.00` which will show `.00` for whole number and will show `1.1` as `1.10`. I think it would be safer to nest **TEXT** function somewhere within the function to specify the format.

Comment: I tried to add **TEXT** to the formula but it will convert `number` into `text` so even though it is showing the correct decimals as requested but they were not in numeric form which might be a problem for calculation. If I use `--` to convert them back to number, it will still show `5.00` or `1.10` if the cell format is predetermined to show two decimal places. I guess your answer would probably be the best among all constraints.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF((INT(A1)=A1)=FALSE,IF(AND(A1>0,A1<1),TRUNC(A1,2),TRUNC(A1,1)),A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with *whole numbers* also showing 1 decimal place (so `5 -> 5.0`) then you can use a custom number format *(there is also ways to use this method to hide the decimal on a whole number, but that would also require a using conditional formatting).*

Select the range you want to format, then right click. Click on **Format Cells**, then select the **Custom** category.

Enter this in the 'Type' field:

```
[<1]0.00;0.0
```

---

Pros:

- Doesn't require a helper column
- Retains the original cell value. *(If this is not desirable, then you can simply round or truncate the number. But this would require a formula [hence helper column] or possibly VBA)*

Cons:

- Will still format a whole number with `.0`. So `5 -> 5.0`

You can find more information about custom format codes here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68

Answer (score 2):

One more formula option:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,(MOD(A1,1)>0)+(INT(A1)=0))
```

[image]